# Why do we need a depository and clearing center today?

Tags: stock-exchanges, settling-and-clearing, depositary-receipts

I imagine that Back In The Day, the depository kept real securities in some safe and gave physical receipts about the presence of such a quantity of funds in such an account. Today, though, all securities are just information on servers, so all this (in theory) can be processed by the exchange itself or the bank in which the user has an account.

Thus, why do we need separate organizations for this, if now everything is in electronic form?

Comment: Why do you think the fact that it's data now, not physical paper, has any bearing on the existence of a clearing house?  Why didn't the bank or exchange just house all the paper?

Comment: @quid I mean that earlier this was all done manually, namely the execution of documents, signatures, stamps, etc., but now all this should happen instantly and all calculations can be transferred online without the need to support organizations and staff for this. or am I misunderstanding the mechanism of work?

Comment: I just don't understand why a shift from physical paper to digital files changes the need for a third party clearing house.  Money and assets are still being transferred around.

Comment: @quid >Money and assets are still being transferred around. but for the transfer of money and assets, there seem to be enough banks, i.e. the sender's bank and the recipient's bank, why else are intermediaries?

Comment: Banks use third party vendors for a variety of types of transactions.  Why do banks use Visa, why not just process transactions in house?  Because a bank isn't in the business of authorizing transactions between customers and merchants.  But also, Charles Schwab (as an example) is not a bank, it's a broker.  There is a Charles Schwab Bank, but legislation requires it to be separate from the brokerage business.  A lot of brokers use Apex clearing, because the brokers are not in the business of clearing transactions.  Anyway, I'll stop now and see if someone has anything to add.

Comment: I had a paper share certificate until mid 2012 and I'm just a dude whose grandmother gave it to me long ago.  Do you have a source for "all securities are just information on servers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there was an established system that worked, which was well tested, and which everyone involved knew how to use.  If you are a sensible software developer, in going from paper to electronic data you change as little of that as possible.  In other words, IF IT AIN'T BROKE, DON'T FIX IT.

Comment: If I'm a stock exchange who can save a lot of money by performing the digital repository functions myself, then I probably would.

Comment: @RonJohn: But how much do you lose in productivity by getting everyone to use an unfamiliar system?  Even something as simple as changing accounting packages can cost a lot in retraining time & fixing the inevitable errors.

Comment: There is also that little scenario that is overlooked in that a clearing house is NOT EXCHANGE SPECIFIC. Particularly in the US and stocks there are a ton of exchanges and you can buy/sell where you want for every transaction. Clearing houses serve as neutral arbiter of handover and trust center also BETWEEN exchanges.

Comment: @jamesqf that's a very stagnant mindset.

Comment: @RonJohn: Yes, it is, and I think that's a good thing.  As I said, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  Indeed, I'd go further: don't change something that works unless the improvements are greater than the costs.

Comment: @james the first automobiles were manifestly worse than horses.  Your mentality means that we'd still be riding horses everywhere.

Comment: A lot of times you have to start fixing things to realize how broken they are.

Comment: @RonJohn: Not a comment to make to a horse owner :-)  And in many ways, automobiles are still manifestly worse that horses.  But the point you need to think about here is that the first automobiles weren't an immediate replacement for horses.  There were decades in which the two co-existed, while the support infrastructure for automobiles developed.  Imagine the chaos if one day, say in 1900, the government said no more horses, everything switches to automobiles.

Comment: @jamesqf and the NYSE wouldn't release it's own depository until it was functional; therefore, your analogy is flawed.

Comment: @RonJohn: They wouldn't release it until they THOUGHT it was functional.  If you've ever worked in software development, you might have noticed that real-world users have this unfortunate habit of breaking software in ways that the developers never suspected were possible.  But you're still arguing around my point, which that there is an existing system which works, and works well: what benefits would outweigh the costs and potential risks of changing it?

Comment: @jamesqf why are there multiple spreadsheet programs, if Lotus 1-2-3 worked *well enough*?  MS-DOS worked *well enough*.  The Mosaic browser worked *well enough*.  PDP operating systems from DEC worked *well enough* that Unix didn't have to be developed.  WordStar worked *well enough*.  You develop a competitor because **you think you can make money**.